# Refactoring and removing unused CSS from SASS/LESS files

Tags: css, refactoring, less, single-page-application

I am working on a big **single page application [backbonejs and rails]** which has LESS as the CSS preprocessor and the generated .css files has grown to such an extent that for IE we have to split it into 3 files with http://blesscss.com/

Though there are tools to detect unused css and linting css, I am unable to find a proper solution for refactoring LESS/SASS files directly from uncompiled files instead of a single large generated .css file.

Would like to know what is the best approach doing these tasks?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 11):

1. For finding and remove unused CSS use [Uncss](https://github.com/giakki/uncss) which has implementation as tasks for Grunt and Gulp
2. For finding unused variables in your SASS/LESS code- some script like [this one](http://blog.gospodarets.com/finding_unused_scss_variables/).
3. For debug source files instead one generated css- [source maps](http://thesassway.com/intermediate/using-source-maps-with-sass)
4. To minify your code, use [compressed output styles](http://web-design-weekly.com/2014/06/15/different-sass-output-styles/)
5. To automatically add vendor prefixes for browsers in your css use [Autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer)
6. Generally- provide [Grunt](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass) or [Gulp](https://github.com/dlmanning/gulp-sass) build for your css

P.S.: Some of the links are just for SASS- for Less there are similar solutions which are easy to find.

Answer (score 0):

> I am using koala fro minify and combine SASS,LESS,CSS,JS

[see koala](http://www.koala-app.com) and [Docs](https://github.com/oklai/koala/wiki)