# Detect and remove unused LESS

Tags: css, less, refactoring, mapping

I can't figure out a way to **detect unused LESS** to remove it.

Since it is possible to do so with CSS (via uncss), there has to be a way to use the mappings and get instructions on which LESS parts to remove. So how can I use uncss and the mappings to actually make this happen?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20811204/refactoring-and-removing-unused-css-from-sass-less-files) is similar but is only about variables.

Thank you in advance for any help

Comment: AFAIR there's no tools or libs that can manipulate Less code (not counting compilers themselves).

Comment: Also the mappings trick (in case one is planning to make such tool) is not  that helpful actually: CSS mapping just points to the beginning of some statement but neither marks the end of the statement nor marks any outer statements it could depend on. Take for instance a trivial [loop](http://lesscss.org/features/#loops-feature) - sourcemap will point you to just `width: (10px * @counter);` line but won't give any hint on how and where `@counter` comes from. So in general a much deeper analysis is required.

Comment: True @seven-phases-max. I will have to find a solution anyway, since it can't be hand-made due to the huge amount of files I need to process. Still looking into it...

Comment: found anything?