# Tree shaking sass

Tags: javascript, node.js, sass

I have a large project with many old/unused SCSS files. Is there any way, using `node-sass` or `libsass`, to tree-shake or remove all files that weren't used in the compilation?

Or is there a way to simply output a list of all files used in the compilation so that I can cross reference?

edit: Although there seem to be solutions to remove unused styles from the *output* of the sass build, I still don't see an efficient way to remove unused *input* files

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Refactoring and removing unused CSS from SASS/LESS files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20811204/refactoring-and-removing-unused-css-from-sass-less-files)

Comment: Although I dont have answer to it, but it would be interesting to know if any such solution exists. One way I can think of is to use devtools coverage reporter but that need to run all scenarios to tell you exactly which code is unused and thus not a reliable option.

Comment: Solution based on @ScottSword's link seems usage of something like: https://github.com/uncss/uncss

Comment: uncss looks like it removes unused styles, which would be useful as a build step. But my question is more about being able to remove unused SCSS files from the project to decrease confusion during development.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With sass if you set the `:line_comments` option to true the generated output will contain the line number *and source file* where each rule was defined.  You should get output like:

```
/* line 20, sass/_reset.sass */
body {
  line-height: 1;
  color: black;
  background: white;
}
```

With node-sass the option is [`sourceComments: true`](https://github.com/sass/node-sass#sourcecomments).

```
gulp.task('styles', function() {
    return gulp.src('src/sass/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass({ 
        style: 'expanded',
        sourceComments: true
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('path/to/file.css'))
```

So do something like that, then you can do:

```
grep '^/\* line \d*, .*\*/' path/to/file.css
```

and you will get output like:

```
path/to/file.css:/* line 20, sass/_reset.sass */
```

And then you'll just have to write some script to remove the files that don't appear in that list.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It was extremely helpful but I ran into issues with sass partials and deeply nested files. 

For anyone coming from google, I ended up writing a little utility that traverses the sass import tree and diffs it with the sass files in a directory: [sass-shake](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass-shake)

Answer (score 3):

[Here](https://gist.github.com/badsyntax/6193491) you find a shell script.For both SCSS and less.
follow this instruction 

1. create a file with .sh with this script 

2. run chmod +x ./your-file.sh

3. run ./your-file.sh less/sass


hope this will help you 

thanks.